# C# DBNull and nullable Types - cleanest form of conversion

Tags: c#, datatable, types, nullable

I have a DataTable, which has a number of columns. Some of those columns are nullable.

```
DataTable dt;  // Value set. 
DataRow dr;  // Value set. 

// dr["A"] is populated from T-SQL column defined as: int NULL
```

What, then, is the cleanest form of converting from a value in a DataRow, to a nullable variable.

Ideally, I would be able to do something like:

```
int? a = dr["A"] as int?;
```

***Edit***: Turns out you CAN do this, the side effect being that if your Schema types arn't ints, then this is ALWAYS going to return null. The answer by Ruben of using `dr.Field<int?>("A")` ensures type mismatches don't silently fail.  This, of course, will be picked up by thorough unit tests.

Instead I'm usually typing something along the lines of:

```
int? a = dr["A"] != DBNull.Value ? (int)dr["A"] : 0;
```

This is a bunch more keystrokes, but more importantly, there's more room for someone to stuff something up with a wrong keystroke. 
Yes, a Unit Test will pick this up, but I'd rather stop it altogether.

What is the cleanest, least error-prone pattern for this situation.

Comment: the "int? a = dr["A"] as int?;" works for me!

Comment: Indeed, it does. Sorry, misread what was blowing up on me. If only this were an answer, I would've marked it as such.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[The LINQ to DataSets chapter of LINQ in Action](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/2/f43421d-7e2e-419b-a12d-b55984f0ecd3/bonusch14.pdf) is a good read.

One thing you'll see is the `Field<T>` extension method, which is used as follows:-

```
int? x = dr.Field<int?>( "Field" );
```

Or

```
int y = dr.Field<int?>( "Field" ) ?? 0;
```

Or

```
var z = dr.Field<int?>( "Field" );
```

Comment: Fantastic. This is great. Turns out my original suggestion works too, but this has the advantage of making sure that you're not silently returning nulls because of an incorrect type spec.

Comment: Ta. May I commend you on your selection :P IMNSHO `as` is definitely overused - you dont want silent nulls happening. BTW the book itself is good too - better than the APress one, though its hard to beat C# in Depth for general LINQ priming.

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink: The link in your answer is broken. What if I want to use this with `DbDataReader` or `IDataReader`? Which `using` do I need to make `Field<int?>` work?

Comment: @Paul No it's not broken :) (I assumed the same a while back but do a retry and it works). The `Field<T>` stuff is in most places you'd expect it - i.e. I'd be surprised if `IDR`/`DBDR` didn't have it. The key missing bit, as you allude to is that you need to add a FW ref to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` -- [most of the extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions(v=vs.110).aspx) are in the obvious namespaces (i.e., mainly `System.Data`).

Comment: is dt a DataTable?  shouldn't it be a DataRow?

Comment: @mikeW nice spot after 7+ years ;)

Answer (score 14):

This is the purpose of the `DataRowExtensions` class in .NET 3.5, which provides static `Field<T>` and `SetField<T>` methods for round-tripping nullable (and non-nullable) data between the `DataRow` and .NET types.

```
int? fld = row.Field<int?>("ColumnA")
```

will set `fld` to `null` if `row["ColumnA"]` contains `DBNull.Value`, to its value if it contains an integer, and throw an exception if it contains anything else.  And on the way back,

```
row.SetField("ColumnA", fld);
```

does the same thing in reverse:  if `fld` contains `null`, it sets `row["ColumnA"]` to `DBNull.Value`, and otherwise sets it to the value of `fld`.

There are overloads of `Field` and `SetField` for all of the value types that `DataRow` supports (including non-nullable types), so you can use the same mechanism for getting and setting fields irrespective their data type.

Answer (score 4):

```
int? a = (int?)dr["A"]
```

Comment: Whether you use this or the aformentioned "int? a = dr["A"] as int?;" would be dependant on how much you trust you schema i guess.

Comment: @RhysC: If I cant trust my schema, I want to know about it. I dont want a silent null arriving just because someone coverted my field to a sligtly different type. This way you hear about it in your tests as an exception.

Comment: Of course, I has the dumb. Was totally misreading what was blowing up on me!

Comment: Will is right. Throws InvalidCastException when DBNull is returned. Works fine when there is a value though.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use LINQ? It does the conversion for you.

Comment: @Ralph: This post inspired mine. One thing to get used to around here is that a code sample speaks a thousand words in terms of votes. Nobody but me has upvoted this as you didnt expand on what you meant and assumed the questioner would figure it out from your pithy remark. (Just saying: I was in the same boat until someone pointed this out in comments to me - thanks whoever you were!)

Comment: Obviously I'm not holding my response in here up as a shining example of garnering deluges of votes worthy of A Horse, but you get my drift.

Answer (score 1):

Following would work, safely:

**Snip:**

```
public static class SqlDataReaderEx
{
    public static int TryParse(SqlDataReader drReader, string strColumn, int nDefault)
    {
        int nOrdinal = drReader.GetOrdinal(strColumn);
        if (!drReader.IsDbNull(nOrdinal))
            return drReader.GetInt32(nOrdinal);
        else
            return nDefault;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
SqlDataReaderEx.TryParse(drReader, "MyColumnName", -1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work with the DataTable/DataRow that I already have.

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods!

Something like the following:

```
public static class DataRowExtensions
{
    public static Nullable<T> GetNullableValue<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)
        where T : struct
    {
        object value = row[columnName];
        if (Convert.IsDBNull(value))
            return null;

        return (Nullable<T>)value;
    }

    public static T GetValue<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)
        where T : class
    {
        object value = row[columnName];
        if (Convert.IsDBNull(value))
            return null;

        return (T)value;
    }
}
```

Use it like so:

```
int? a = dr.GetNullableValue<int>("A");
```

or

```
string b = dr.GetValue<string>("B");
```

Comment: Why would you write a set of extension methods that replicates the extension messages that the kind people at Microsoft have already written for exactly this purpose?

Comment: You're right. I forgot about LINQ to DataSet. Might as well use the built-in functionality.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static object GetColumnValue(this DataRow row, string columnName)
{
    if (row.Table.Columns.Contains(columnName))
    {
        if (row[columnName] == DBNull.Value)
        {
            if (row.Table.Columns[columnName].DataType.IsValueType)
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(row.Table.Columns[columnName].DataType);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return row[columnName];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

To call the function you could write

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ColumnName");
....
Add rows in Datatable.
....
dt.Rows[0].GetColumnValue("ColumnName);
```

Comment: This is a worse answer than all/most others. It returns everything as an object, so the caller has to manually do casting. You should review the accepted and highly voted answers to help improve your code.

Answer (score -4):

```
   Chart.data = new List < int ?> ();
   Chart.data = (from DataRow DR in _dtChartData.Rows
    select(int ? )((DR[_ColumnName] == DBNull.Value) ? (int ? ) null : (int ? ) DR[_ColumnName])).ToList();
```

Comment: Could you explain what this code does and how that fixes the problem?