# Is there an easy way to check multiple columns to see if the value is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting a parameter and getting a specific product from a stored procedure.  This stored procedure is returning many columns (I think around 15-20).  Unfortunately, some of these values may be null and this of course produces an error when I try to put them in a variable.  Is there a simple way to check and see if these values are `NULL` so that it doesn't throw an exception or do I need to put an `if` statement before each assignment?  If it helps, here is my code:

```
public List<Product> ReadSpecificProductDetails(string productAndURLID)
    {
        ConfigureDataAccess();
        myCommand = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[GetSpecificProductDetails]", myConnection);
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //myCommand.Parameters.Add(productAndURLID);
        //myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProductID", SqlDbType.SmallInt));
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", Convert.ToInt16(productAndURLID));

        try
        {
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (SqlException exception)
            {
                exception.Data.Add("cstring", myConfiguration);
                throw;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                ex.Data.Add("cStatus", myConnection.State);
                throw;
            }

            //Create a 'Product' list to store the records in
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                int productID = Convert.ToInt16(myReader["ProductID"]);
                string productName = (string)myReader["Name"];
                string productNumber = (string)myReader["ProductNumber"];
                //int quantitySum = Convert.ToInt16(myReader["QuantitySum"]);
                string productColor = (string)myReader["Color"];
                int productSafetyStockLevel = Convert.ToInt16(myReader["SafetyStockLevel"]);
                int productReorderPoint = Convert.ToInt16(myReader["ReorderPoint"]);
                decimal productStandardCost = Convert.ToDecimal(myReader["StandardCost"]);
                decimal productListPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(myReader["ListPrice"]);
                string productSize = (string)myReader["Size"];
                decimal productWeight = Convert.ToDecimal(myReader["Weight"]);
                int productDaysToManufacture = Convert.ToInt16(myReader["DaysToManufacture"]);
                string productCategoryName = (string)myReader["PC.Name"];
                string productSubCategoryName = (string)myReader["PS.Name"];
                string productModelName = (string)myReader["PM.Name"];
                DateTime productSellStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader["Sell_Start_Date"]);
                DateTime productSellEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader["Sell_End_Date"]);
                DateTime productDiscontinuedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(myReader["Discontinued_Date"]);
                Product p = new Product(productID, productName, productNumber, productColor, productSafetyStockLevel, productReorderPoint, productStandardCost,
                    productListPrice, productSize, productWeight, productDaysToManufacture, productCategoryName, productSubCategoryName, productModelName, productSellStartDate,
                    productSellEndDate, productDiscontinuedDate);
                myProducts.Add(p);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            myReader.Close();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        return myProducts;
    }
```

Comment: I strongly suggest using LINQ-to-SQL to map your DB into classes which makes these things extremely simple and easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int? x = dt.Field<int?>( "Field" );
```

Or

```
int y = dt.Field<int?>( "Field" ) ?? 0;
```

[C# DBNull and nullable Types - cleanest form of conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706405/c-sharp-dbnull-and-nullable-types-cleanest-form-of-conversion)

The top is probably your best approach.  You currently have some non nullable types you are populating.  So if you want to be able to represent them as null use the top approach.  Otherwise you can use the other option to give a default value.

Comment: I've used the nullable type in combination with my solution below. It works great. I've run numerous unit tests for it. I like your suggestion as well.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ will be your best friend in these types of situations, as ssg suggested in the comments, however if you want to make a very large addition of null checking, you could implement something like the following:

```
int productID = (myReader["ProductID"] != null) ? Convert.ToInt16(myReader["ProductID"]) : 0;
```

or you could simply use an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Peform a check for DBNULL for the field you may suspect is a null value. In this case all of them.

```
if (! DBNull.Value.Equals(row[fieldName])) 
      return (string) row[fieldName] + " ";
   else
      return String.Empty;
```

What you can do is create a function that has several overloads for int, string, and DateTime parameters that checks for null

So it would look something like this:

```
public string CheckNull(string value)
{
   if (! DBNull.Value.Equals(value)) 
          return value;
       else
          return String.Empty;
}
```

This way you would only have to do something like

```
object.stringProperty = (string)CheckNull(row["columnName"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the direct mapping between a data reader and DTO, I use the IsDbNull() method of the data reader. Here are a couple of examples using different data types:

```
myObj.MyStringProperty = !myReader.IsDBNull("myStringColumn") ? myReader["myStringColumn"].ToString() : null;
myObj.MyNullableDecimalProperty = !myReader.IsDBNull("mydecimalColumn") ? decimal.Parse(myReader["mydecimalColumn"].ToString()) : new decimal?();
```