# What would be the best control/easiest way to output a single record with many columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is a continuation from this: 
[Is there an easy way to check multiple columns to see if the value is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407025/is-there-an-easy-way-to-check-multiple-columns-to-see-if-the-value-is-null)

Now that I've got my single product, it's far too wide to display on my webform with a gridview.  What do you guys recommend that I use?  I thought about outputting it as a table with two columns: the first will state what the data represents and the second column will have the actual data.  Is this a bad idea?  If not, I'm not really sure how I would do this anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll typically want to display only a few columns that describe the product (ID, Description, etc) in a GridView. One of the columns can contain a link to a details page that will display everything else.

I'm not sure that its an official pattern, but this idea is often called Master/Detail.

Comment: I did do this.  I have a gridview with all the products and 4 columns.  One of these columns contains a link that will link to that specific product with multiple columns.  I'm not sure how I should display this.

Comment: You can use a DetailsView to display the product details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.aspx